# Short Time Fourier Transform (spectrum analysis) in parallel & lazily using Dask (and / or xarray)

Tags: python, scipy, dask, python-xarray

### **Question:**

I am trying to do spectrum analysis on long time series data (see example for data structure, it is basically 1d data with a time index). To save time and memory etc. I want to do this parallel and lazily (using xarray and / or dask).
*What would be the best (or a better) way to do this?*

### **What I tried:**

(see below for examples & code)

1. using scipy.signal.stft with xr.apply_ufunc:
   **Problem:** ValueError, only works if input data is 1 chunk, which does not work with large data.
2. using using scipy.signal.stft with dask.array.from_delayed:
   **Problem:** Output data is always 1 chunk which makes it hard to further work with the data. (rechunking afterwards overloads RAM)
3. Intermediate (lazily) 2d transformation using xr.Dataset.rolling.construct. Here 1 dimension is time and the rows are the short time windows over which I do the fft ("rolling window").

   with data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and a rolling window of 3 this would become:

   | time index | rolling window |
   | --- | --- |
   | 00:00:00 | NaN, NaN, 1 |
   | 00:00:01 | NaN, 1, 2 |
   | 00:00:02 | 1, 2, 3 |
   | 00:00:03 | 2, 3, 4 |
   | 00:00:04 | 3, 4, 5 |

   Then using xr.apply ufunc to calculate the fft over each time point row (vectorized) over this new array, also lazily (see example below for specifics).
   This works and because it is lazily computed it works with big data sets too.

   **Issues**:

   - seems slower than scipy.signal.stft (see benchmarks below)
   - overlap/stepsize can not be changed (as with noverlap in scipy stft).
   - is the intermediate step really needed or is there a way to immediately calculate the rolling window fft?
   - Still overloads RAM in some cases

*Other*: I also tried other methods such as optimizing the function with numba (but that doesn't work well with np.fft.fft) but to keep this already long post short I only included the most promising methods I tried.

What can I do to do this, and / or increase performance of method 3 or use method 1 or 2, or something else to lazily and parallel using xarray / Dask?

Thanks!

### Code / Examples:

**imports & test dataset:**

```
import xarray as xr
import dask.array as da
import dask
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as ss

# variables
fs= 128           # rec frequency
_l = int(1e3)     # data length
window = fs * 10  # window over which to do stft


# Create data 
data = np.random.random(_l * fs)
data = xr.DataArray(da.from_array(data, name="x")).assign_coords({"dim_0":np.arange(_l * fs)})
data = data.chunk(chunks=_l/10 * fs)   # create multiple chunks to simulate bigger data
data = data.to_dataset()
```

**Method 1:**

```
def stft(data,):
    f, t, Zxx = ss.stft(data,
                        fs=fs, 
                        nperseg=window,
                        noverlap= window - 1
                        )    
    return np.abs(Zxx)

data['fft'] = xr.apply_ufunc(stft,
               data.x,
              input_core_dims=[['dim_0']],
              output_core_dims=[["f", "t"]],   # define newly created output dims
              dask="parallelized",
              output_dtypes=['f8'],
              output_sizes={"f": window / 2 + 1, 
                            "t": data.x.size - 1},
              )
```

output:

```
ValueError: dimension 'dim_0' on 0th function argument to apply_ufunc with dask='parallelized' consists of multiple chunks, but is also a core dimension. To fix, rechunk into a single dask array chunk along this dimension, i.e., ``.chunk({'dim_0': -1})``, but beware that this may significantly increase memory usage.
```

**Method 2:**

```
def stft1(x):
    f, t, Zxx = ss.stft(x,
                        fs=fs, 
                        nperseg=window,
                        noverlap=window - 1
                        )    
    return np.abs(Zxx)
    
da.from_delayed(dask.delayed(stft1)(data.x), shape=(window / 2 + 1, data.x.size - 1), meta="f8")
```

output:
[image: Method 2 output]

**Method 3: (working but not optimal?)**

```
def xr_make_fft(ds, par):
    ds['roll_window'] = np.arange(window)  # create dimension for rolling window
    
    # FFT function to apply vectorized:
    def xr_fft(x):
        fft = np.fft.fft(x)[xr_fft.idx]
        return np.abs(fft)
    
    # make new parameter with rolling windows stacked
    ds['FFT_window'] = ds[par].rolling(dim_0=window).construct("roll_window",)
    
    # Calc FFT Freq domain
    fftfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(window, 1 / fs)
    idx = (0 < fftfreq)
    freq = fftfreq[idx]
    ds['Frequency'] = freq
    xr_fft.idx = idx
    
    ds[f'FFT'] = xr.apply_ufunc(xr_fft,
                                ds[f"FFT_window"],
                                vectorize=True,
                                input_core_dims=[["roll_window"]],  # define input dim over which to vectorize (this dim in inserted completely)
                                output_core_dims=[["Frequency"]],   # define newly created output dims
                                dask="parallelized",
                                output_dtypes=['f8'],
                                output_sizes={"Frequency": len(freq)},
                                )
    
    ds = ds.drop(f'FFT_window').drop_dims('roll_window')
    return ds

data = xr_make_fft(data, "x")
```

output:
[image: method 3 output]

**performance test on small dataset:**
128e3 length data (largest dataset which did not overload RAM):

**Method 2:**

```
%timeit da.from_delayed(dask.delayed(stft1)(data.x), shape=(window / 2 + 1, data.x.size - 1), meta="f8").compute()
3.53 s ± 28.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Method 3:**

```
%timeit data.FFT.compute() 
6.04 s ± 219 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**scipy.signal.stft**

```
%timeit ss.stft(data.x, fs, nperseg=window, noverlap=window-1)[2]
1.87 s ± 8.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing multiple methods, this seems to be the best solution:

***Create example data & imports:***

```
import dask.array as da
import dask
import numpy as np

fs = 128                            # sample rate
_l = int(5e6)                       # n samples, change if you like

data = da.random.random(_l * fs)    # really long array with random numbers
```

#### SOLUTION (using dask array):

This solution uses sliding_window_view to create a 2d transformation of a sliding window over the data, then applies the fft on that 2d window (as proposed/explained in the question).

You can always add the output dask array to an xarray dataset if needed. You can also apply this method over dask arrays embedded in xarray datasets.

***step 1:***
chunk the data so with the 2d tranformation it has good sized chunks (rechunking later is costly / leads to crashes). To test what chunksize works best, test it on a small sample and check how big the chunks of the fft_window (see step 3) variable are.

```
data = data.rechunk(chunks=24000)  # 24000 works great on my 16 GB system adjust if needed
```

2d window *with* rechunking:

[image: 2d window with rechunking]

2d window *without* rechunking:

[image: 2d window without rechunking]

***step 2:***

calculate the fft parameters and create the fft function

```
FFT_WINDOW = 10 * fs                             # use a 10 second window
fftfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(FFT_WINDOW, 1 / fs)     # create fft freq array
idx = (0 < fftfreq)                              # create index of positive freq
freq = fftfreq[idx]                              # create freq  array

# create fft function:
da_fft = lambda x: da.absolute(da.fft.fft(x, axis=1)[:, idx]
```

***step 3:***
do the 2d transform and calculate fft

```
with dask.config.set(**{'array.slicing.split_large_chunks': False}):          # surpress warning
    fft_window = da.overlap.sliding_window_view(data, FFT_WINDOW)[:, ::-1]   # [:, ::-1] is to backward fill window
    fft = da_fft(fft_window)
    PAD_LEN = data.size - fft.shape[0]
    fft = da.pad(fft, ((PAD_LEN, 0), (0, 0)), constant_values=np.nan)         # pad to match original array
```

NB: if dask version < 2021.03.1 use numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view with da.map_overlap instead. Performance is comparable

**output**:
[image: fft output]

**Performance** (calculate mean over 100000 points):

- Method 3 from question (adding step 1 from here to prevent mem overload):
  `5.36 s ± 72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- Method proposed here:
  `1.83 s ± 52.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`